# How to work on server without the site being actually online?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, hosting, server-side

I have a wordpress site, I need to work on it on my server but i don't want the site to be online in any way shape or form. i want to complete the site completely and only then launch it, how can i do this?

thanks,
edit: im currently using xampp, but facing issues, so i want to shift to my server.

Comment: Any reason why you would develop on your server and not on your local host as suggested by @Karl below?

Comment: well, im trying to get in certain functionalities on the website but it seems xampp is getting in the way of its smooth functioning, thats the reason why i wanna go to my server (but not online at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Take the wordpress files out of the documentroot (where your files are displayed from)and put them in some temporary document and set up virtualhosts on your server so that you can have more than one documentroot so you can test it in your browser but it wont be live.

Comment: so your saying, i should install xampp on the server itself? and work on the xampp through my actually paid server?

Comment: It should already have a software that displays web pages if your wordpress site is live, but you could actually just block all traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like MAMP or WAMP, MAMP works on both windows and macs, these are local server environments which you install on your own computer. You can then develop them on your computer and once finished, upload the files to the production server. This is quite common practice.

If however, you want to use your server you could block all connections which do not come from your own IP Address. For example in your .htaccess file you could put:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

Comment: the 2nd option is quite interesting concept, but could this cause any permimant damage once i complete the site and want search engines to visit will there be any complications then?

Comment: No, it wouldn't cause permanent damage, but it could affect your rankings whilst the block is in place. The only way around this is to keep your current site as it is, create a new virtualhost on your server with perhaps a temporary domain name and develop using that. Then once complete, copy the files over the live sites files.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me working on development of a WordPress site I would do it one of 2 ways:

1) Either create a new VirtualHost and password protect it

2) Use a local instance of Apache to serve the WordPress installation locally.

Option 2 is probably the handiest. Pushing the new site live is then a simple case as uploading the theme directory to the live environment and enabling it, provided you keep all relevant files within the theme directory.

Apache can be installed using either LAMP (for Linux) or WAMP (for Windows)